# Image Processing Toolbox(MATLAB) in Python

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, toolbox

Good day everyone! Is it possible if I can import the toolbox to Python? I am currently converting a script from MATLAB to Python and the script used some IPT toolbox functions and I don't really know what libraries I should use as an alternative to Python. If you could recommend anything it would be appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[opencv-python](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) is a wide-known package, [scikit-image](https://www.mathworks.com/products/image.html) is also a good choice, but it depends on your actual needs.